# ¿como puedo filtrar una lista de años?

Tags: c#

estoy tratando de filtrar una lista de años cuando se repitan, estoy usando Distinct() para filtrar pero no me resulta el resultado que necesito.

El metodo que estoy probando para hacer el listado es este

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Liquidaciones()
    {


        List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();


        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2022", Value = "2022" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2022", Value = "2022" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2022", Value = "2022" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2022", Value = "2022" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2023", Value = "2023" });


        //Agregamos la lista a nuestro SelectList
        SelectList miSL = new SelectList(lst, "Value", "Text");

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listb = from x in miSL.Distinct()
                                            select new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = x.Text.ToString(),
                                                Value = x.Value.ToString()
                                            };

        return listb;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un objeto derivado de una clase es igual a otro si comparte la misma dirección de memoria.

El error común es pensar que son iguales cuando sus propiedades son iguales, esto funciona para la estructuras y para los records, pero no para las clases.

Es decir, tu creaste 4 objetos del tipo SelectListItem que aunque tengan las mismas propiedades son objetos distintos, porque ocupan espacio de memoria distinto, porque a cada uno de ellos los creaste con "new"

Soluciones:

**1) Usar DistinctBy**

```
from x in miSL.DistinctBy(a=>a.Value)
```

Si quisieras comparar por más de una propiedad puedes crear una tupla

```
from x in miSL.DistinctBy(a=>(a.Value, a.Text))
```

**2) Usar Groupby**

```
from x in miSL.GroupBy(a => new { v = a.Value, t = a.Text })
select new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x.Key.t.ToString(),
    Value = x.Key.v.ToString()
};
```

**3) Usar Tuplas**

```
List<(string Text, string Value)> lst = new List<(string , string)>();

lst.Add(("2022","2022"));
lst.Add(("2022", "2022"));
lst.Add(("2022", "2022"));
lst.Add(("2022", "2022"));
lst.Add(("2022", "2023"));

IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listb = from x in lst.Distinct()
                                    select new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = x.Text.ToString(),
                                        Value = x.Value.ToString()
                                    };
```

**4) Usar [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0)**

```
class SelectListItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<SelectListItem>
{
    public bool Equals(SelectListItem b1, SelectListItem b2)
    {
        return b1.Value == b2.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SelectListItem bx)
    {
        return bx.Value.GetHashCode();
```

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Liquidaciones()
{


    List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();


    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2022", Value = "2022" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2022", Value = "2022" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2022", Value = "2022" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2022", Value = "2022" });
    lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2023", Value = "2023" });

    var comparer = new SelectListItemEqualityComparer();
    //Agregamos la lista a nuestro SelectList
    SelectList miSL = new SelectList(lst, "Value", "Text");
          
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listb = from x in miSL.Distinct(comparer)
                                        select new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                            Text = x.Text.ToString(),
                                            Value = x.Value.ToString()
                                        };

    return listb;
}
```

Comment: la lista miSL no me trae la propiedad DistinctBy() tampoco me sale la opcion de importarla :(

Comment: @AndresEdu He actualizado la respuesta con 5 posibles soluciones

Comment: ok voy a probar y te comento si funciona

Comment: Me corrijo, son 4 soluciones distintas

Comment: Usando group by me funciono, tenia un metodo parecido y lo adapte a este metodo gracias bro de nuevo